# Execute program with random number as a parameter in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I include an random number in a string in Inno Setup?

```
[Run]
#define rndH Random(24) 
#define rndM Random(60)

Filename: "schtasks"; \
  Parameters: "/Create /F /SC DAILY /ST {rndH}:{rndM} /RU SYSTEM /RL HIGHEST /TN ""Program Title"" /TR ""'{app}\program.exe'""";
```

When I try the code above, I get an error

> [ISPP] Undeclared identifier: "Random"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your answer works, but it is unnecessarily complicated:

- Use [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) parameter, to avoid creating two functions that differ just by a constant;
- Use [`Format` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_format) to pad the number to two digits;
- No need to use global variables (though my version does not need any variables at all actually).

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks"; \
  Parameters: "/Create /F /SC DAILY /ST {code:MyRand|24}:{code:MyRand|60} ...";
```

```pascal
[Code]

function MyRand(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := Format('%.2d', [Random(StrToInt(Param))]);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a question like this, i managed to do it with the code bellow.

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks"; \
  Parameters: "/Create /F /SC DAILY /ST {code:MyRandH}:{code:MyRandM} /RU SYSTEM /RL HIGHEST /TN ""Program Title"" /TR ""'{app}\program.exe'""";

[Code]
var
  h: Integer;
  m: Integer;

function MyRandH(Param: String): String;
begin
  h := Random(24);
  if h < 10 then
    Result := '0' + IntToStr(h)
  else
    Result := IntToStr(h);
end;

function MyRandM(Param: String): String;
begin
  m := Random(60);
  if m < 10 then
    Result := '0' + IntToStr(m)
  else
    Result := IntToStr(m);
end;
```